# How to sum value of specific keys in an Axios Response

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

I have a response from an Axios get call that returns data as follows:

```
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-14", Income: 12333}
{StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-15", Income: 9829}
{StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-16", Income: 11945}
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-17", Income: 10335}
{StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-18", Income: 12801}
{StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-19", Income: 8528}
{StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-20", Income: 11183}
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-21", Income: 14747}
{StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-22", Income: 10503}
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-23", Income: 9594}
{StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-24", Income: 10810}
{StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-25", Income: 12389}
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-26", Income: 13758}
{StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-27", Income: 8011}
```

what I need to do is create a subsequent object in the form of the below to apply to the state of the component:

```
{StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-14", Income: 12222333}
{StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-15", Income: 33212123}
{StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-16", Income: 4323432}
{StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-27", Income: 83333}
```

Where the Income is the Sum of all the previous Income in the Object returned from Axios for that given store. The number of stores changes from client to client so I cannot set up a hardcoded dictionary with each store name, rather needs to build dynamically based on the site (store name) or the StoreId.

I have gone back and forth trying different approaches and now gone back to square one with:

```
    axios.get('/incomeforallsites/' + this.state.userid + '/' + Moment(this.state.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '/' + Moment(this.state.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '/1') //Call to NodeJS to retrieve the data for the sites based on the users affiliation
     .then( response => {
         console.log(response.data);
        response.data.forEach(site => {
            console.log(site.site);
            console.log(site.Income);

        });          

        this.setState({
            data: response.data,
        }); 
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Data Error : retrieving multisite summary data.")
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ dataError: true });
    });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, even if a direction on how to approach this. I believe that map might be an answer but haven't been able to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create your array of summed objects like this:

```js
const response = [
  {StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-14", Income: 12333},
  {StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-15", Income: 9829},
  {StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-16", Income: 11945},
  {StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-17", Income: 10335},
  {StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-18", Income: 12801},
  {StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-19", Income: 8528},
  {StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-20", Income: 11183},
  {StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-21", Income: 14747},
  {StoreId: 222, site: "Store 2", Date: "2020-03-22", Income: 10503},
  {StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-23", Income: 9594},
  {StoreId: 333, site: "Store 3", Date: "2020-03-24", Income: 10810},
  {StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-25", Income: 12389},
  {StoreId: 111, site: "Store 1", Date: "2020-03-26", Income: 13758},
  {StoreId: 444, site: "Store 4", Date: "2020-03-27", Income: 8011}
];

const summedResponse = response.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let inAcc = false;
  acc.forEach(o => {
    if (o.StoreId == cur.StoreId) { // if obj store is already in new array, increase sum
      o.Income += cur.Income;
      inAcc = true;
    }
  });
  if (!inAcc) {
    acc.push(cur); // if obj store isn't already in new array, add it
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(summedResponse);
```

Comment: Unbelievable!! Thank you. I would never have gotten there on my own. In order to understand it, should I be researching reduce and map functions?

Comment: @Elad no problem, and yeah take a look at the link I included describing the `reduce` function. Basically what it does is take a function which accepts a variable number of arguments (but it must at least take `accumulator` and `currentValue`) and returns the `accumulator`. In this case, I am using the `accumulator` and `currentValue` arguments and then building an array (which is the `accumulator` in this case) by combining the similar objects into one object and then including them in the returned `accumulator` array